# Unable to open files in USB flash drives

Tags: usb-flash-drive

When I want to open my USB flash drives, it has an error with the below text:

```
There was a problem starting~$WUDFFPBD.FAT
The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you tried it on another port or better... another computer?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to see if linux can open your USB flashdrive.Download Ubuntu or any other linux OS you like, burn it to a DVD and boot in live mode ( no install ).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a malware on your memory. Check this out, like photo:

1. goto folder option
2. select view tab
3. check show hidden files and folders
4. uncheck Hide protected operating system.
5. click on Apply button and check your memory again

[image]

My Previous advice:

If your mean is your cool-disk or your memory disk so try to format it via [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Hard-Disk-Utils/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool.shtml)

HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool is a tiny freeware utility which has been designed for the HP Drive Key or DiskOnKey USB 2.0 devices. Installing it does not represent a problem whatsoever, since it is very compact and it can be run out-of-the-box, i.e. no installation is actually required.

but if your mean is your motherboard ports, goto device manager and re-install your USB drivers again ...
[image]

Comment: i don't want to  format it because i need its information.
when i open the USB drive there is a shortcut that its size is 1KB and when i want to open that shortcut i receive a message with that text i said in my question.

Comment: tnx for your answer
i did it before but it didn't work too

Comment: check this way, goto Command (cmd), and goto your memory letter for example you should write like this : "E:" and push the enter! now, write "dir /ah", push the enter again. do you see all of your files and folders on your memory ???

Comment: i did it and i received the below text
date   <DIR>
date   0 autorun.inf
date   3,337.ini
date   763,760 Thmbs.db
       3 Files    767,097 bytes
       1 Dirs   2,370,711,552 bytes free

Comment: @Mike: you don't get "a" malware. You get SOME malware. Just like you don't have "a" software. Or "a" water. If you want to talk about a single instance of malware, you would say "a piece of malware". Generally people say "you have malware" because it is an unknown quantity of malware.

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers, thank you Austin, I really want someone to help me in English , I wish you could; it's my pleasure if you accept me as your student, my email : s.fisher@inbox.com

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to this question

[USB flash drive empty folders](https://superuser.com/questions/691629/usb-flash-drive-empty-folders/691779#691779)

I would recommend you to try connecting your USB Drive to Linux Operating System and check if you can open the files.

If the files are not present, you can use tools like Recuva and try to recover your files.